# Font on CSS won't load

Tags: html, css, fonts

I was trying to use google fonts on CSS for my webpage but instead of rendering the chosen font, it showed the default sans-serif font. What changes could I make to the code?

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Black', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>test</h1>
```

Comment: The name of the font is in the URL: just `Montserrat`, not `Montserrat-Black`. If you need more than just regular weight (i.e. weight value 400) remember to tick every weight box you need and then use the new URL that Google web fonts gives you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to use the Black version of Montserrat. Here is how you can do it:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400; /* This value changes from font to font. It's like a value of its boldness */
font-weight: bold; /* That's a way too */
```

Answer (score 0):

First way: For using black version of this font you can import just black version:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

In this way, for using Black version of Montserrat you can just set `font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;`

Second way: Also you can import all versions and Give `font-weight: 900;` to every where you wanna be black version.

.............

If you need just black version, do first way. Else second.